# Can I cast a DateTime to Bit for a boolean evaluation if DateTime is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, casting

I am relatively new to .Net and SQL Server and I need to be able to do a boolean check on a DateTime datatype for a null value.

I am using the following statement which is clearly wrong as it returns an Int32 in my Visual Studio immediate window while debugging.  I am using linq to call a stored procedure which interrogates a bunch of tables.

The markup that some of the result collection will be bound to look like this;

```
<asp:Image  ID="imgAuthorised" ImageUrl='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AuthorisedDate")?"/Horizon/Images/save16x16.png":"/Horizon/Images/delete16x16.png" %>' runat="server" ToolTip='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AuthorisedDate")?"Authorised":"Not Authorised" %>' />
```

Depending on the boolean value of the collection returned then I want to display an appropriate image.  Here is my attempt(ahem) to do an evaluation within the stored proc'

```
CASE WHEN dbo.Expense.AuthorisedDate is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as AuthorisedDate
```

I have tried casting this statement like so;

```
CAST(CASE WHEN dbo.Expense.AuthorisedDate is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as bit) as AuthorisedDate
```

Feel free to giggle at any school boy errors or poor understanding as I'm a dot net newb (hence the name :P) ha!

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand what I am doing wrong and what to do/avoid in future when attempting to do stuff like this.

TIA

dotnetnewb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about extending your model?  Your stored procedure (lets assume it's called `GetMyData`)  will likely return an ISingleResult.

If so, go to your DBML, view code (assuming this is a web application) and create a new partial class:

```
public partial class GetMyDataResults
{
    public bool IsAuthorised
    {
        get { return DateAuthorised.HasValue; }
    }
}
```

And then you should be able to:

`<asp:Image  ID="imgAuthorised" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsAuthorised")?"/Horizon/Images/save16x16.png":"/Horizon/Images/delete16x16.png" %>' runat="server" ToolTip='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsAuthorised")?"Authorised":"Not Authorised" %>' />`

Alternatively, you can piggyback onto the OnItemDataBinding event and do the work in there, though the above would be the easier path I'd think.

Cheers,
Terry

Comment: Thanks Terry, are you implying that I edit the dbml directly, or create an external partial class to extend the model? Cheers

Comment: This worked! Thing is though if I need to rebuild my dbml which is likely, I will lose those changes......So an external partial class is a reasonable solution.  Thanks T!

Comment: ahh, when you do 'ViewCode' it should create a new DbmlFilename.cs file for you and it's never overwritten when you re-generate the dbml stuff, though your solution (separate cs file) obviously works just as well - nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(dbo.Expense.AuthorisedDate is null) as HasAuthorisedDate
```

Comment: Thanks, probably should have mentioned that I tried that also, it does not like that syntax and recognises it as a string value if i put it in single quotes.

Comment: In SQL `true` is expressed as `1` and `false` as `0`

Comment: @dotnetnewb I should point out that this will also work: `SELECT CAST('true' AS Bit)`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement with the CAST is correct:

The SQL datatype of bit is the closest to .net "boolean" you'll get.

Note: you will only ever get a number 1 or 0 from a bit datatype. There is no false or true because it isn't boolean

Comment: Thanks for your post.  When the collection is returned my 1 or 0 is recognised as an Int32 by the compiler.  So if your saying my SQL syntax is correct but it returns a different data type, is there no other way around it?

Comment: @dotnetnewb: Pretty much. There must be some other reason in your web code that the "bit" is lost because I know that bit is directly convertable to boolean types in .net